# Can 'Often' be categorised as quantifier(Determiner)?

Tags: determiners, quantifiers

Since 'Often' can also denote quantity, can it be called a quantifier?

Comment: No, the adverb "often" functions as a frequency adjunct, as in "Do you come here often?"

Answer (score 1):

"Often" is a relative adverbial quantifier, quantifying events instead of entities, just like "twice" would be an absolute adverbial quantifier. They can be easily compared to more common nominal quantifiers like "most" (relative) or "seven" (absolute).

It is, however, not a determiner.

EDIT:

Montague, R. (1973):
 *The Proper Treatment of Quantification in Ordinary English*, in Hintikka, K. J. J. (ed.), *Approaches to Natural Language: Proceedings of the 1970 Stanford Workshop on Grammar and Semantics*. Springer Netherlands. pp. 221--242. ([PDF](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/~zhaohui/montague73.pdf))

Lewis, D. (1975): *Adverbs of Quantification*, in In Edward L. Keenan (ed.), *Formal Semantics of Natural Language*. Cambridge University Press. pp. 178--188. ([a later PDF](http://www.andrewmbailey.com/dkl/Adverbs_of_Quantification.pdf)).

Comment: As Matt Gutting has said, "Hi! What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer: one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case a [grammar], dictionary, or [academic paper]). Edit your question and put in your support; then we'll be able to vote up your answer!" // Be aware that there is a school of thought not classing numerals as quantifiers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: There is a school of thought for everything, apparently. To me, quantifiers are no more and no less than words that perform quantification, in a logical sense (a predication on the cardinality of a set), and as such they are an objective category orthogonal to the (not that objective) part of speech system. A logical (or semantic) category, if you will, as opposed to the syntactic category that is "determiner".

Comment: I'm not a 'CGEL is correct by definition' fanatic, but neither do I subscribe to  'CGEL is wrong by definition' – far from it. Note BillJ's response above, doubtless taken from CGEL. But +1 for the references.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I generally agree with every part of BillJ's response, except the first word. I do not possess a copy of CGEL, but browsing online I find this quote: "We use *quantification and quantifier as semantic terms*, noting that there is no one-to-one relation between them and the *syntactic category of determinatives*" (GCEL, Chapter 5 - Nouns and noun phrases, section 5 - Quantification, emphasis mine), which says exactly what I was trying to express. Saying "no, they're adjuncts" there is like answering "is milk a liquid?" with "no, it's dairy". It can be both.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Furthermore, "Adjuncts of frequency express quantification in the clause in a way which is comparable to that of quantifiers in the structure of NPs: [...] Frequency adjuncts quantify situations..." (CGEL, Chapter 8 - The clause: adjuncts, Section 9 - Adjuncts of frequency). Syntactically, they're adjuncts. Semantically, they are quantifiers. (I wish I remembered to take a look into CGEL when I first answered.)